# Feasible positive solutions to linear system of equations

Tags: reference-request, linear-programming

Suppose $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ with $n < m$ and $\mathrm{rank}(A) = n$. I'm interested in knowing if there are algorithms (or software) that can find the set of $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that there exists a positive $x$ that satisfies $A x = b$. A brute-force way to start doing this by hand is applying Farkas' lemma, but it doesn't seem very practical. Any pointers to literature would be appreciated!

Comment: Isn't this exactly what Gaussian elimination is for?

Comment: It is the cone generated by the columns of $A$.

Comment: Thanks! My question went on algorithms to find the set itself, given $A$. Are you aware on any software that does that? This is kind of like asking if there is software that finds the feasible set of an LP.

Comment: @ShiwenYao: The answer is given by my comment above. How do you want the cone to be described?